# Jupyter_Kernel error_%1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, pywin32

I've installed Anaconda 4.9.2 64-Bit to my Windows 10 64-Bit. Wanted to open Jupyter within it's shortcut, but it didn't work. Then I tried to open Jupyter through Anaconda prompt with command `jupyter notebook`.
It opened, I created new python-file, but it had Kernel error. In Anaconda prompt I had this output:

```
File "C:\Users\usermane\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 461, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
File "C:\Users\usermane\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 387, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[W 12:00:31.891 NotebookApp] Unhandled error
```

I aslo tried to do these things:

1. I've already imported within Anaconda prompt `import win32api` to python and then `pip install pypiwin32` and `pip install --upgrade jupyter_client` just in Anaconda prompt.
2. Copied files in a directory "Lib/site-packages/pywin32_system32", which including two dll libs (pythoncom38py.dll and wintypes38.dll), and pasted them to the "/Lib/site-packages/win32" directory.

But the error still persists.